# cash vs hard cash

Tags: difference

I have just read the following headline:

> Google wants you to complete simple tasks for hard cash in its new app.

According to the Cambridge dictionary, "[hard cash](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hard-cash)" means "money in the form of coins and notes, but not a cheque or a credit card". That is the exact definition of "[cash](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cash)" in the Cambridge dict. So, is there any difference between both?

Comment: “hard” is acting as an flourish for emphasis. They are trying to suggest it is ‘real’ money rather than credit which is unlikely to be literally true for something coming from Google so probably more marketing ‘puff’ than an actual description of the reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between *cash* and *hard cash*. I had always assumed that part of the reason it was called hard was to emphasise how hard it is to acquire it rather than referring to its physical properties since, after all, notes are quite soft. As @jwpfox says in a comment in this case it is just a rhetorical flourish and Google is not promising to send you a wad of your favourite currency.